# for each file made i want to create a directory with several folder inside

Tags: powershell

**csv file contents:**

```
NAME DATE
mike today
Lisa today
```

**code:**

```
Set-Location "C:\New folder"
$Folders = Import-Csv C:\csfon123456-PREP.csv | For each ($Folder in $Folders) {
    New-Item $Folder.Name -type directory -Force
}
```

Comment: example c:new folder\lisa\stormfolder\date\lastknown\

Comment: `for each` is not a command. If you are piping to `foreach`, you are actually using `foreach-object`. The current object then is `$_` or `$PSItem`. So you'd use `foreach { New-Item $_.Name -Type directory -Force}`.

Comment: for some reason when i tried to post it it won't take it together

Comment: Please press the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65329597/edit) link to edit your question. Don't add additional information only as comments. Also please add what the actual output is from your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When piping into `foreach`, you are piping into [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1) because `foreach` is its alias. This differs from the [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1) statement, which uses the syntax `foreach ($item in $collection) {}`.

**Using `Foreach-Object` or alias `foreach`:**

```
Import-Csv C:\csfon123456-PREP.csv | foreach {
    New-Item $_.Name -Type Directory -Force
}
```

**Using `foreach` statement:**

```
$Folders = Import-Csv C:\csfon123456-PREP.csv
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    New-Item $folder.Name -Type Directory -Force
}
```

Notice that you do not pipe into the `foreach` command.

---

As an aside, you can view aliases using [Get-Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias?view=powershell-7.1).

```
Get-Alias # lists all command aliases
Get-Alias foreach # lists the commands that use foreach as an alias
```